# Dependencies with React install issue

Tags: reactjs, npm, package, git-bash

```
npm install axios moment react-file-base 64 redux redux-thunk
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\apa10\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-10-17T18_50_39_698Z-debug-0.log
No matches found for "npm" "install" "axios" "moment" "react-file-base" "64" "redux" "redux-thunk"
```

While I am trying to install dependencies for the client, as below, the following errors were shown. What does it mean and how can I resolve it?

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove space between `react-file-base` and `64` from package list.
So, you just need to run below command to install packages.

```
npm install axios moment react-file-base64 redux redux-thunk
```